# Using modal_bottom_sheet how would I recreate the functionality of SingleChildScrollView with textfield input?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, flutter-layout, flutter-plugin

I wanted to use the plugin modal_bottom_sheet to create a MaterialBottomModal view that has a single text field and a button to verify the password of the user.

Currently, if the user tries to enter their details, the keyboard will cover the MaterialBottomModal completely blocking the view of the modal. Therefore users cannot see what they are typing.

I can make the overall size of the modal bigger so the keyboard can fit but at that point, I could have just created another screen.

Hi @jamesblasco, hope this is possible within the current scope. Thanks for your plugin, its awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your modal's content with a Padding.
The workaround below should help.

```dart
Padding(
   padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
   child: ...,
)
```